# How to prevent application crashes and not reply message again and again ?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I make application that are when receive a specific message it getting message string and pass the message string to the  upload message method and get data from given url and reply back to the same number but this application some time crash and show force close and sms reply again and again what should I do that make my application not reply back sms again and again and not crash.

Incomingsms.java

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {
 String senderNum;
 String message;
 String url;
 String casetype;
 String no;
 String caseyear;
 String result;

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Bundle myBundle = intent.getExtras();
     SmsMessage [] messages = null;
     String strMessage = "";
     String msgFrom = "";
     String msgText = "";


     if (myBundle != null)
     {
         Object [] pdus = (Object[]) myBundle.get("pdus");
         messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

         for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++)
         {
             messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
             strMessage += "SMS From: " + messages[i].getOriginatingAddress();
             msgFrom += messages[i].getOriginatingAddress();
             strMessage += " : ";
             strMessage += messages[i].getMessageBody();
             msgText += messages[i].getMessageBody();
             strMessage += "\n";

         }

         Toast.makeText(context, strMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            try {

              String regex = "[\\s;.,:'!?()-]";
              String text =msgText ;

              String[] sms = text.split(regex);
                 for(int i = 0; i < sms.length; i++)
                      {


                      casetype = sms[0];
                      no = sms[1];
                      caseyear = sms[2];   

                      }         

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                    {
                System.out.println(e);
           Toast.makeText(context, "wrong msg" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

       url = "http://www.allahabadhighcourt.in/casestatus/caseDetailA.jsp?type=" +
          casetype + "&num=" + no + "&year=" + caseyear;

            try 
            {
                result = uploadMessage(context,url);
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


             SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
             sms.sendTextMessage(msgFrom, null, result, null, null);

     }  

   }



      public  String uploadMessage( Context context, String url)
     {

   //System.out.println(url);
   try{
   Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(20*1000).get(); 
   if (!doc.hasText()){
       System.out.println("doc empty");
   }
     Element pending = doc.select("table td:eq(0)").first();
   Element nextDate = doc.select("table td:eq(0)").get(10);
   //Element date1 = doc.select("table td:eq(0)").get(11);
   Element date = doc.select("table td:eq(1)").last();


   String data =   pending.text()+"\n" + nextDate.text()+"\n"+ date.text();
   return data ;
   }catch(Exception ex){
       System.out.println("" + ex.getMessage());
       return "Nodata" ;
   }
   }
  }
```

BroadcastNewSms.java

```
    public class BroadcastNewSms extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.androidexample_broadcast_newsms);
}
  }
```

Android Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" >

</uses-permission><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" >

</uses-permission><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >

</uses-permission><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" >

</uses-permission><receiver android:name="com.androidexample.broadcastreceiver.IncomingSms" >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>

</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your broadcast receiver start a service (because that's the recommendation. Broadcast receivers have to be short lived. They're just triggers. You can't make them do too much work).

Have that service use AsyncTask (because not using a separate thread is what's causing the occasional ANR - Application Not Responding and the force close in your case).

Comment: please sir explain in detail